# Decimal Multiplication of Strings

Tags: code-golf, string

Given two inputs, a string \$s\$ and a decimal number \$n\$, output the string multiplied by that number.

The catch is that the number can be a float or an integer.

You should output the string \$\lfloor n \rfloor\$ times and then the first \$\lfloor (n - \lfloor n \rfloor) \cdot |\,s\,|)\rfloor\$ characters again.

Other notes:

- The input will not always be a float, it may be an integer.
  So `1.5`, `1`, and `1.0` are all possible.
  It will always be in base 10 though, and if you wish an exception please comment.
- The string input may contain white space except newlines, quotes and other characters.
  Control characters are excluded, too, if this helps.
- No built-ins for direct string repetition are allowed.
  That means for instance Python’s `'a'*5` is forbidden.
  Nevertheless string concatenation (frequently denoted by the `+` sign) is allowed.

### Test cases

| \$s\$ | \$n\$ | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `test case` | `1` | `test case` |
| `case` | `2.5` | `casecaseca` |
| `(will add more later)` | `0.3333` | `(will` |
| `cats >= dogs` | `0.5` | `cats >` |

### Final Note

I am seeing a lot of answers that use builtin string multiplication or repetition functions.
This is *not* allowed.
The rule is:
If it directly multiplies the string, you cannot do it.

Comment: The wording was modified repeatedly (I did not see the first revision). I suggest to remove `direct` string repeating (what does this mean?). But all in all you're right

Comment: [Related quine version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62711/quine-multiple-times)

Comment: @Sp3000 yeah, I know.  I think the difference is significant enough.

Comment: "No built-ins for direct string repeating, even string multiplication like the python 'a'*5 are allowed." You don't explain the difference between these. They sound the same to me.

Comment: @edc65 In Perl you can do list repetition then concatenate the elements of that list, which isn't direct string repetition. In Perl 5: `join "", ("case") x 2` vs `"case" x 2`, in Perl 6 `[~] "case" xx 2` vs the same `"case" x 2`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills yes, that is allowed.  So are stack duplication operators and number*number multiplication.

Comment: I'm not voting to close, since I would hammer this and I consider it a bit of a grey area, but I believe this is being voted unclear because of the "no builtins" clause. See [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/56656).  Although If anyone who actually voted would like to comment I would take their word over mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Jelly, 5 bytes

```
×L}Rị
```

Doesn't use a repetition built-in. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5dMfVLhu4s&input=&args=Mi41+Y2FzZQ)

#### How it works

```
×L}Rị  Main link. Left input: n (multiplier). Right input: S (string)

 L}    Yield the length of S.
×      Multiply it with n.
   R   Range; turn n×len(S) into [1, ... floor(n×len(S))].
    ị  Retrieve the elements of S at those indices.
       Indices are 1-based and modular in Jelly, so this begins with the first and
       jump back after reaching the last.
```

Answer (score 7):

### Java 7, 89

```
void g(char[]a,float b){for(int i=0,l=a.length;i<(int)(l*b);)System.out.print(a[i++%l]);}
```

takes char[] and float and outputs to STDOUT. basic looping.

Comment: Good golfing, even for java. :P

Comment: this was suggested on my other answer too, but i don't think i will do this. it does not seem right to me.

Comment: Eh, fair enough. It is recognized here, but alright. :D

Comment: I recommend declaring your language as Java 7. Then no one can tell you to use lambdas.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

**Edit** 2 bytes more to include definition of function `f`. 1 byte less using the tip of @manatwork. Note: using `~` we have more iterations than necessary, but this is code golf and even 1 byte counts

```js
f=(s,n,l=s.length*n)=>~n?f(s+s,n-1,l):s.slice(0,l)
```

**TEST**

```js
f=(s,n,l=s.length*n)=>~n?f(s+s,n-1,l):s.slice(0,l)

//TEST
console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'
;[
 ['test case', 1, 'test case'],
 ['case', 3.5, 'casecasecaseca'],
 ['(will add more later)', 0.3333, '(will '],
 ['cats >= dogs', 0.5, 'cats >']]
.forEach(t=>{
  var s=t[0],n=t[1],x=t[2],r=f(s,n);
  console.log("«"+s+"» "+n+' => «'+r+'» '+(x==r?'OK':'FAIL expected '+x));
 })
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.  So far most of the answers have had no problem, and it is really easy to fix.  Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: Tiny typo: `n>0` in the code vs. `n>1` in the test case.

Comment: @manatwork thanks. It should work either way

Comment: Oh. Indeed. But then why not just `~n`? (Really just a question. Tried only the given test cases.)

Comment: @edc65 Where is `f` defined in your solution? Aren't you missing `f=`?

Comment: @dev-null oh oh oh you'r perfectly right, this is recursive. My fault. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <del>9</del> 8

```
s@Lz*lzQ
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to Pietu1998

This takes `floor(n * len(string))` letters from the string, using cyclical indexing. I believe this is always equivalent to the given formula.

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%40Lz%2alzQ&input=case%0A2.5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=test+case%0A1%0Acase%0A2.5%0A%28will+add+more+later%29%0A0.3333%0Acats+%3E%3D+dogs%0A0.5&debug=0&input_size=2)

Comment: No plz don't take this from me this soon. xD

Comment: @VoteToClose I actually didn't read your answer at all, scouts honour :P I didn't even realise that string repetitions were disallowed, this was just shorter that what I came up with that way...

Comment: You don't even need the second `s`. `range` is funny like that.

Comment: NOO! *cries in a corner* Ah, oh well.

Answer (score 4):

## Vitsy, 9 bytes

Expects the word as an argument, and the number to multiply by through STDIN.

```
zlW*\[DO{]
z          Grab all string argument input.
 l         Get the length of the stack.
  W        Parse STDIN.
   *       Multiply the top two items (length of string and the number of repetitions)
    \[   ] Do the stuff in the loop.
      DO{  Output one char at a time, making sure to duplicate first.
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=emxXKlxbRE97XQ&input=Mi41&args=Y2FzZQ)

Comment: True to your word, you answered *fast*.

Comment: @RikerW Martin out FGITW'd me.

Comment: Why do you `Grab all string argument input.` and then `Parse STDIN.` again?

Comment: @RikerW Arguments that are doubles are automatically parsed, pushing them to the stack immediately. Handling that takes more bytes than it's worth.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 10 bytes

```
l_,l~*,\f=
```

The string is supplied on the first line of STDIN, the float on the second.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l_%2Cl~*%2C%5Cf%3D&input=cats%20%3C%3D%20dogs%0A0.5)

#### Explanation

```
l    e# Read string.
_,   e# Duplicate and get its length.
l~   e# Read second line and evaluate.
*    e# Multiply them. If the result, N, was floored it would give us the number of
     e# characters in the required output.
,    e# Get range [0 1 ... ⌊N⌋-1].
\f=  e# For each character in that range, fetch the corresponding character from the
     e# string using cyclic indexing.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 71 bytes

```python
lambda s,x:"".join(s for i in range(int(x)))+s[:int(len(s)*(x-int(x)))]
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/Bknh)

Creates an unnamed lambda which takes the string as first argument and the float as second. Returns the repeated string.

This could be 46 if string repetition builtins were allowed :(

Comment: Much sad. Such string multiplication rules. +1 A+ for effurt.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>49</s> 48 characters

```ruby
->s,n{(0...(n*l=s.size).to_i).map{|i|s[i%l]}*''}
```

Sample run:

```
2.1.5 :001 > ->s,n{(0...(n*l=s.size).to_i).map{|i|s[i%l]}*''}['case', 2.5]
 => "casecaseca"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>46 41</s>  39 bytes

```perl6
{([~] $^a xx$^b)~$a.substr(0,$a.chars*($b%1))}    # 46 bytes
{substr ([~] $^a xx$^b+1),0,$a.chars*$^b}         # 41 bytes
{substr ([~] $^a xx$^b+1),0,$a.comb*$b}           # 39 bytes
```

Perl 6 has both a string repetition operator `x` and a list repetition operator `xx`.

Since the rules disallow string repetition, we repeat it as if it was a single element list instead. Then the list gets concatenated together, and a substring of it is returned.

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &code = {substr ([~] $^a xx$^b+1),0,$a.chars*$^b}
#          {substr ($^a x$^b+1),0,$a.chars*$^b}

say code('test case', 1).perl;                  # "test case"
say code('case', 2.5).perl;                     # "casecaseca"
say code('(will add more later)', 0.3333).perl; # "(will "
say code('cats >= dogs', 0.5).perl;             # "cats >"
```

Comment: `substr ([~] $^a xx$^b+1),0,$a.comb*$b}` saves two chars

Answer (score 2):

## osascript, 173 bytes

Oh my days, this is worse than I thought.

```
on run a
set x to a's item 1's characters
set y to a's item 2
set o to""
set i to 1
set z to x's items's number
repeat y*z
set o to o&x's item i
set i to i mod z+1
end
o
end
```

Returns the value of the string, another answer using cyclical indexing. Expects input as `"string" "repetitions"`.

Comment: `Oh my days, this is worse than I thought.` So true, so true.

Comment: Is there a multiple var set at once command? ie `set x,y to a's items`?

Comment: @RikerW I don't think so. If there is, I'm seriously missing out.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
c x=x++c x
s#n=take(floor$n*sum[1|a<-s])$c s
```

Usage example: `"(will add more later)" # 0.3333` -> `"(will "`.

How it works: `c` concatenates infinite copies of the string `x`. It behaves like the built-in `cycle`. `sum[1|a<-s]` is a custom length function that works with Haskell's strict type system as it returns a `Double` (the built-in `length` returns an `Int` which cannot be multiplied with `n`). `#` takes `floor (n * length(s))` characters from the cycled string `s`.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP 5, <s>96</s> 87

9 bytes saved thanks to @manatwork

```php
<?for($i=$z=0;$i++<floor(strlen($a=$argv[1])*$argv[2]);$z++)echo$a[$z]?:$a[$z=0‌​];
```

Pretty straight forward looping answer.

#### Ungolfed

```php
<?
$a=$argv[1];
$z=0;
for($i=0; $i < floor(strlen($a)*$argv[2]); $i++) {
    // if the string offset is not set
    // then reset $z back to 0 so we can
    // echo the beginning of ths string again
    @$a[$z] ?: $z=0;
    echo $a[$z];
    $z++;
}
```

Comment: Not sure when should that error suppression help, for me seems to work without `@` too: `<?for($i=$z=0;$i++<floor(strlen($a=$argv[1])*$argv[2]);$z++)echo$a[$z]?:$a[$z=0];`

Comment: I was getting a notice on case #2 which caused the output to render incorrectly, which is when I added in the suppression. (running in CLI mode)

Comment: “PHP 5.3 or later, the default value is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED.” – [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) So we prefer to base our solutions on default configuration and not to care about notices and other good habits. For example ignoring the initialization of `$z` and `$i`.

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 51 + 3 = 54 bytes

```
$l=<>*y///c;for$i(1..$l){push@a,/./g}say@a[0..$l-1]
```

Requires: `-n`, `-l` and `-M5.010` | `-E`:

```
 $ perl -nlE'$l=<>*y///c;for$i(1..$l){push@a,/./g}say@a[0..$l-1]' <<< $'test case\n1'
 test case
 $ perl -nlE'$l=<>*y///c;for$i(1..$l){push@a,/./g}say@a[0..$l-1]' <<< $'case\n2.5'
 casecaseca
 $ perl -nlE'$l=<>*y///c;for$i(1..$l){push@a,/./g}say@a[0..$l-1]' <<< $'(will add more later)\n0.3333'
 (will 
 $ perl -nlE'$l=<>*y///c;for$i(1..$l){push@a,/./g}say@a[0..$l-1]' <<< $'cats >= dogs\n0.5'
 cats >
```

Explanation:

```
$l=<>*y///c;              # Calculate output length (eg. 2.5 * input length)
for$i(1..$l){push@a,/./g} # Push a lot of chars from input into @a
say@a[0..$l-1]            # Slice @a according to output length
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 59 bytes

```R
function(s,l)cat(rawToChar(array(charToRaw(s),nchar(s)*l)))
```

As an unnamed function.  This uses charToRaw to split the string into a vector of raws.  This is filled into an array of length * l, converted back to char and output.
I was going to use strsplit, but it ended up being longer.

Test

```R
> f=
+ function(s,l)cat(rawToChar(array(charToRaw(s),nchar(s)*l)))
> f('test case', 1) # -> test case
test case
> f('case', 2.5) # -> casecaseca
casecaseca
> f('(will add more later)', 0.3333) # -> (will(space)
(will 
> f('cats >= dogs', 0.5) # -> cats >
cats >
>
```

Answer (score 1):

## c (preprocessor macro), 71

```
j,l;
#define f(s,m) l=strlen(s);for(j=0;j<(int)(l*m);)putchar(s[j++%l])
```

Not much tricky here.  Just need to make sure `l*m` is cast to an `int` before comparing to `j`.

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/eOZpew)

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, <del>154</del> 152 bytes

```
WITH v(s,i)AS(SELECT SUBSTR(:1,1,FLOOR(FLOOR((:2-FLOOR(:2))*LENGTH(:1)))),1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT :1||s,i+1 FROM v WHERE i<=:2)SELECT MAX(s)FROM v;
```

Un-golfed

```
WITH v(s,i) AS
(
  SELECT SUBSTR(:1,1,FLOOR(FLOOR((:2-FLOOR(:2))*LENGTH(:1)))),1 FROM DUAL 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT :1||s,i+1 FROM v WHERE i<=:2
)
SELECT MAX(s) FROM v;
```

I went the recursive way, with the initialisation select taking care of the decimal part.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @MickyT

Comment: You can save a couple by removing spaces after the ) in the WITH clause and the final select.

Comment: Another saving would be to replace `FLOOR(FLOOR((:2-FLOOR(:2))*LENGTH(:1)))` with `MOD(:2,1)*LENGTH(:1)`

Comment: And one last one :), you can use `LPAD` rather than `SUBSTR`

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 24 bytes

```
,╗,mi@≈╜n╜l(*≈r`╜E`MΣ)kΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LOKVlyxtaUDiiYjilZxu4pWcbCgq4omIcmDilZxFYE3OoylrzqM&input=InRlc3QiCjIuNQ)

Explanation:

```
,╗,mi@≈╜n╜l(*≈r`╜E`MΣ)kΣ
,╗                        get first input (string) and push it to register 0
  ,mi@≈                   get input 2 (x), push frac(x) (f), int(x) (n)
       ╜n                 push n copies of the string
         ╜l(*≈            push length of string, multiply by f, floor (substring length) (z)
              r`╜E`MΣ     push s[:z]
                     )kΣ  move fractional part of string to bottom, concat entire stack
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 9 bytes

```
V*Elzp@zN
```

Basically just doing

```
             z = input()
V*Elz        for N in range(evaluatedInput()*len(z)):    # flooring is automatic
     p@zN        print(z[N], end="")                     # modular indexing
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 138 B

This full `program` requires a processor compliant with ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”.
Trivial cases have been excluded:
It is presumed that the input string `s` is *non-empty* and `n` is *positive*.
NB:
The golfed version caps `s` at a reasonable length of `999`.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var s:string(999);n:real;begin
read(s,n);while n>1 do begin n:=n-1;write(s)end;write(s[1..trunc(length(s)*n)])end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program decimalMultiplicationOfStrings(input, output);
    var
        { `string` is a schema data type defined by Extended Pascal.
          The `string(maxInt)` discriminates the schema data type.
          Henceforth the specific `string` has a capacity of `maxInt`. }
        s: string(maxInt);
        n: real;
    begin
        { You can specify `real` as well as `integer` literals for `n`.
          An `integer` value is automatically promoted to `real`. }
        read(s, n);
        { The `string` subrange notation used below in the last line
          may not specify an empty range (e. g. `1‥0` is illegal).
          Therefore the `while` loop’s condition is `n > 1`.
          If `n = 1`, the one copy is printed via the final line. }
        while n > 1 do
        begin
            n ≔ n − 1;
            write(s);
        end;
        { The subrange notation is defined by Extended Pascal.
          It cannot be used for strings that are `bindable`. }
        write(s[1‥trunc(length(s) * n)]);
    end.
```

Input is end-of-line separated.
`s` can otherwise contain any character from `chr(0)` to (the implementation-defined) `maxChar` range.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 75 bytes

```
func r[S,F](s:S,n:F):S=
 for i in 0..<int n*s.len.float:result&=s[i%%s.len]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY_NCoJAFEb3PsVFMJywwQohhmzppqVLcTHoTA2MMzF3pIdpI0QP1dskptS3POf-8D2eRnXD8Oq93BzeZ9mbBlxVJkUdIysTwwrCyjwAaR0oUAZSSo_KeDBrpFoYKrXlnjmBvfarHCsVRZOo55M30VwtuDj0Aj00HEWYwJamJFjEzHY0-7H4rrQG3rbQWSdAcy8cGYdSuh_zv-sRTjm09oKTzsj371LpAw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 68 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xCsIwEIb3PsUhCBepQQWXSgqCi4OTOIlDWtMaTZOSnIKUPnuM9Lbvvp@7P9TSyOiqp6oJTlJbGLIM4CMNNAWeyWvb5gf3roxiopwYRMSQ28TDP2dE4EbZlh47XAE5QLswjJM7WlquGe9kj1qUAfXcsISv6coYAe6qgS49RenbUMDee/m9TvrGCrhYTSBSI0jTpy0Ziw3OahnULIcN3zKW3JiN8Qc)

```scala
(s,n)=>{val l=s.length;(0 to (n*l).toInt-1).map(i=>s(i%l)).mkString}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BawIxEIXv/oqHUEiKLCJ4ESwUehHsSTxJD7NruqaNs0syCiL727djthV7msmb92a@pIoC9X1TfrlK8E6ecR0Be/eJ6FpHspHouTZpgaGbgBd4a05lcPZPwzKHgDMFBMf6ToXWWg53edi2zkPDeL75bCHNiiV7zBQnFv9gtMWRWuOxfEHS8pQTKn4PRzXVjX5Rj8ptKNZK@RojXXaD5UMJt@zlzteqKoHNv6@NK0puPMGsmFubt3Z9/wM)

```scala
object Main {
  def repeatString(s: String, n: Double): String = {
    val len = s.length
    val repeatLen = (n * len).toInt
    (0 until repeatLen).map(i => s(i % len)).mkString
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(repeatString("case", 2.5))
  }
}
```