# Multiply a string by a number!

Tags: code-golf, string, number, arithmetic

There was [a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125470/multiply-two-strings) up a while ago about multiplying strings.  It showed us how we can multiply not only numbers, but also strings.  However, we still can't multiply a number by a string properly.  There has been [one attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/decimal-multiplication-of-strings) to do so but this is obviously wrong.  We need to fix that!

### Your Task:

Write a function or program that multiplies two inputs, a string and an integer.  To (properly) multiply an string by an integer, you split the string into characters, repeat each character a number of times equal to the integer, and then stick the characters back together. If the integer is negative, we use its absolute value in the first step, and then reverse the string. If the input is 0, output nothing (anything multiplied by 0 equals nothing).

### Input:

A string that consists solely of printable ASCII characters and newlines, and an integer (possible negative).

### Output:

The string multiplied by the integer.

### Examples:

```
Hello World!, 3            --> HHHeeellllllooo   WWWooorrrlllddd!!!
foo, 12                    --> ffffffffffffoooooooooooooooooooooooo
String, -3                 --> gggnnniiirrrtttSSS
This is a fun challenge, 0 --> 
Hello
World!, 2                  --> HHeelllloo

                               WWoorrlldd!!
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte count wins!

Comment: Can we assume the string is printable ASCII-only, plus newlines?

Comment: Can we output a list of strings?

Comment: Partial solution in Retina. Only works for positive values of the integer. I probably won't make time to finish it if someone wants to. https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/Tk@bS0WLqzhBw97G9tA2PS1NLk6u6oQ4Qy6uWohgnCFQkFNDDyihYqhiyBWTEHdoWw0n1///RlweqTk5@Vzh@UU5KYoA

Comment: @mbomb007, yes, sorry for taking so long about that.

Comment: @totallyhuman, no you may not.

Comment: @Gryphon You said that you cannot output an array of characters. But what if the language can do only that? C is an example, where there is no native string class. You have to use `char[]`, or `char *`. Which are essentially arrays of characters. But one is a pointer to that array.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
²Ɠxm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpmOTK3L/H25/1LQm61HDnEPbdEHg0Lb/6h5AFfkK4flFOSmK6lzqafn5QDK4pCgzLx3ICMnILFYAokSFtNI8heSMxJyc1Lz0VKAMWF9MHlTjf2MdBUMjHQVdIG2go2AEAA)

#### How it works

```
²Ɠxm  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

²     Yield n².
 Ɠ    Read and eval one line of input. This yields a string s.
  x   Repeat the characters of s in-place, each one n² times.
   m  Takes each |n|-th character of the result, starting with the first if n > 0, 
      the last if n < 0.
```

Comment: OK, now I'm really impressed.  I'd love an explanation of this particular wonder in miniature.

Comment: Sure. As soon as I made a test suite and am done golfing.

Comment: OK, if you can make this any smaller, I'm going to give up trying to make a question that will take you >10 bytes.

Comment: Woah. Never seen an input nilad being used before!

Comment: @Zacharý Rarely useful, but dyadic chain rules weren't doing what I wanted.

Comment: @Gryphon Added an explanation.

Comment: OK, that's it.  I'm learning Jelly.  I want to be able to do magic too.

Comment: Wait ... how does `x` not think `m` is an argument?

Comment: @Zacharý In monadic chains, dyads don't bind to each other. That's why I'm using a nilad.

Comment: So ... it sort of becomes post-fix because it has to?

Comment: @Zacharý That's how all chains work: process as many links as possible, skip them, start over.

Comment: *gives up* I guess I'll have to learn Jelly.

Comment: We all know how a discussion about Jelly chains ends up being a mess...

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(s)(n)`.

```js
s=>n=>[...s].reduce((s,c)=>n<0?c.repeat(-n)+s:s+c.repeat(n),'')
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>n=>[...s].reduce((s,c)=>n<0?c.repeat(-n)+s:s+c.repeat(n),'')

console.log(f(`Hello World!`)(3))
console.log(f(`foo`)(12))
console.log(f(`String`)(-3))
console.log(f(`This is a fun challenge`)(0))
console.log(f(`Hello
World!`)(2))
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n:s and s[0]*n+f(s[1:],n)+s[0]*-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU49D4IwEP0r59RWiuFjI2F318QBGKq0UFOvhOLgr69nNV5ueF95ectrmz3WMZrWqcd1VBAkNgEUjhC6YthjZnjoymaQKLKk5BiX1eLGWY/553pkh7u3yCkpAQUYv8IPWoSOs6N2zku4@NWNOyahFhI4M94TLqtETht1TsTzr3mebQB6BeaJcJuVcxonTYEi@amyx39lJQbSNc1ugTER3w)

Comment: The base case seems to ignore the last character.

Comment: Not quite sure why I did that... Thanks!

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY5ND4IwDIb/Sj11g2EUbibcvWviQTxU2WBmdgTw4K@fFY1ND30/8qTDa@4jVym5OtDj2hKwoRrRZNOOgLgFyjh3isXQOWUFp2H0PCtsuPhMw7i@R8/q1wEXR1CTAdbgGc4K9zaEaOAUx9Cu0EClDSh0Mcq9LRdxmIXZiS6@4bH3E8gSuCfDracQLHdWCpslX5AN/5Glvohv5dsaEHV6Aw). but idk if a function call as `f(n,*s)` is considered valid

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>59</s> <s>57</s> <s>50</s> 46 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Anders Kaseorg. -4 bytes thanks to Dennis.*

```python
lambda s,n:''.join(i*n**2for i in s)[::n or 1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ89KXV0vKz8zTyNTK09Lyygtv0ghUyEzT6FYM9rKKk8ByDWM/V9QlJlXopCmoe6RmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6KorqNgrMkFlwsuAbLSgYK6xpr/AQ)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
S²Ä×J²0‹iR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/@NCmwy2Hp3sd2mTwqGFnZtD//0pKSh6pOTn5XOH5RTkpikAul64RAA)

```
S          # Split the string into characters
 ²Ä×       # Repeat each character abs(integer) times
    J      # Join into a string
     ²0‹i  # If the integer is less than 0...
         R #   Reverse the string
```

Comment: TFW you spend 30 minutes trying to come up with something to prove to @Riley that `²0‹i` isn't the best route and come up with literally 0 alternatives.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I've used something like `²0‹i` before and I always think there has to be something better.

Comment: I think I've tried to find an alternative around 10 times now... wasting a cumulative 3 hours of my life ._. `Ä.D)øJ¹0‹iR` is the best I can do without copying you, I think yours is optimized.

Comment: If you care, Emigna used `è` [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131717/59376), though I can't find a way to apply it in this scenario. Would save a maximum of 1 byte, if that.

Comment: `SÂÎ›@²Ä×J`, using `Î` to push 0 and input works if you change the order. Saves 1 byte! (Also replaced the if, so it doesn't need to be closed)

Comment: @kalsowerus That's a completely different approach than mine. Feel free to post it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

### R, <s>83</s> <s>78</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
function(s,i)cat('if'(i<0,rev,I)(rep(el(strsplit(s,'')),e=abs(i))),sep='')
```

Anonymous function.

Frederic saved 3 bytes, Giuseppe saved <s>2</s> 4, pajonk saved 2.

Explanation:

```
     el(strsplit(s,''))                      # split string into list characters
 rep(                  ,e=abs(i)))           # repeat each character abs(i) times


    'if'(i<0,rev, ){...}                     # if i>0, reverse character list
                 I                           # otherwise leave it alone: I is the identity function
cat(                    ,sep='')             # print the result
```

Tests:

```
> f('Hello World!', 3 )
HHHeeellllllooo   WWWooorrrlllddd!!!
> f('foo', 12)
ffffffffffffoooooooooooooooooooooooo
> f('String', -3)
gggnnniiirrrtttSSS
> f('This is a fun challenge', 0)
> f('Hello
+ World!', 2)
HHeelllloo

WWoorrlldd!!
```

Comment: Well done ! You could save a few bytes by writing `rep(foo,,,3)` or `rep(foo,e=3)` (same lenght) ;-)

Comment: @Frédéric you beat me to it, I was going to say the same thing!

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsAgDAXR4@QHsih0W@@ilUgD0oqxvb51OY/ps4RZ3jsPe264GOc0QFYIdmwSu35RIiKja4NW@Ojeqo31EjGLpnyFdDqMV7m2sHgW0KW1PiQ7zx8 "R – Try It Online")

Comment: actually, with Frederic's improvement, that gets you down to 78, which isn't too bad.

Comment: Thanks! @Giuseppe, can you help me understand what your `if` statement is doing?

Comment: yeah, no problem! Basically, I wanted to get rid of the braces, so I needed to get rid of `a=`. Hence, I used the value of `a` as an argument to the reverse function if `i<0`, by having the conditional return the function (which is why I needed the backquotes). But I needed to also apply the identity function for the `i>=0` case, so I used `(` which is close enough. `(` is in fact a function. R is weird.

Comment: btw, the [R docs for Paren](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Paren.html) say that `(` is semantically equivalent to the identity `function(x)x`

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcoxCsMwDEDRvacoWSyBCoWuyV3ipDIRqLGR1EJO73r7PL51lc2yXfDhOOrb8Vbu86OX77mH1BOcBPcckKQkkPlJxj9aYUUwbsAKHuZNJcaZEiLxkjcHwZHObRnWC0wHq9aJXtj/ "R – Try It Online")

Comment: [74 bytes?](https://tio.run/##DcrBCcAgDEDRVYoXE0ih0KsO0DGsRBoQFWO7vvX2efw@0@b2md4Sh9QCSoIxDLCSLIg7qPNHF0LnBpxBR9eWZazPWkRiH24FwZXKzS@bCczDOVdDJ84f "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk is `I` generally a synonym for `(`, or the identity function? If so that's really interesting and I'll update this

Comment: It essentially is an identity function of you don't care about special classes https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/AsIs.html

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>29, 23, 18</s>, 17 bytes

```
æ_ñÀuñÓ./&ò
ÀäëÍî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Cy@MMbDzeUAonJevpqhzdxHW44vOTw6sO9h9f9/@@RmpOTr1CeX5STovhfV/e/rjEA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e65f f1c0 75f1 d32e 2f26 f20a c0e4 ebcd  ._..u.../&......
00000010: ee                                       .
```

Thanks to @nmjcman101 for saving 6 bytes, which encouraged me to save another 5!

The original revision was pretty terrible, but now I'm really proud of this answer because it handles negative numbers surprisingly well. (V has next to no numerical support and no support for negative numbers)

Explanation:

```
æ_          " Reverse the input
  ñ  ñ      " In a macro:
   À        "   Run the arg input. If it's positive it'll give a count. If it's negative
            "   running the '-' will cause V to go up a line which will fail since we're
            "   on the first line, which will break out of this macro
    u       "   (if arg is positive) Undo the last command (un-reverse the line)
      Ó./&ò " Put every character on it's own line
```

At this point, the buffer looks like this:

```
H
e
l
l
o

w
o
r
l
d
!
<cursor>
```

It's important to not the trailing newline, and that the cursor is on it.

```
À           " Run arg again. If it's negative, we will move up a line, and then give the 
            " absolute value of the count. If it's positive (or 0) it'll just give the
            " count directly (staying on the last line)
 ä          " Duplicate... (count times)
  ë         "   This column. 
   Íî       " Remove all newlines.
```

Comment: A few bytes for ya [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/92///DsWxGLXhqw6bDsUhESsOTLi8mw7IKQCLDpMOrw43Drv//LTQKSGVsbG8gd29ybGQh "V – Try It Online")  I always hate the "Negative numbers mean something else!" edge case too.  This is a case where your `0` special cases in V came in super handy.

Comment: Sorry about the negative numbers special.  However, a lot of answers managed to incorporate that into their main answer.  Impressive on this V one though.

Comment: @nmjcman101 Oh wow, that's so obvious, I don't know how I didn't think of it. Thank you!

Comment: @Gryphon Oh I know. The challenge is fine, I just dislike my own language for being so bad at what it's supposed to be good at. :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```hs
f n|n<0=reverse.f(-n)|1<3=(<*[1..n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hrybPxsC2KLUstag4VS9NQzdPs8bQxthWw0Yr2lBPLy9W839uYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBUWZeiYKKQpqCkYJSYlJyihKKoIaukSY2cQOo4H8A)

Example usage: `f (-3) "abc"` yields `"cccbbbaaa"`.

**Edit:** -5 bytes thanks to xnor!

Comment: There's `(<*[1..n])` for `((<$[1..n])=<<)`.

Comment: @xnor Thanks! That's good to know.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
y|Y"w0<?P
```

Inputs are: number, then string.

Strings with newlines are input using char `10` as follows: `['first line' 10 'second line']`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v7ImUqncwMY@4P9/XWMu9eCSosy8dHUA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L@yJlKp3MDGPuB/rEvIf2MudY/UnJx8hfD8opwURXUFLkMjLvW0/Hx1Ll2gXHBJUWZeujqXAZd6SEZmsQIQJSqkleYpJGck5uSk5qWnqnMZcUVDzFBXMDRQUIcaFKsAAA).

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `-3` and `'String'`.

```
y      % Implicitly take two inputs. Duplicate from below
       % STACK: -3, 'String', -3
|      % Absolute value
       % STACK: -3, 'String', 3
Y"     % Run-length decoding
       % STACK: -3, 'SSStttrrriiinnnggg'
w      % Swap
       % STACK: 'SSStttrrriiinnnggg', -3
0<     % Less than 0?
       % STACK: 'SSStttrrriiinnnggg', 1
?      % If so
  P    %   Flip
       %   STACK: 'gggnnniiirrrtttSSS'
       % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>19</strike> <strike>15</strike> 13 bytes

```
(#~|)A.~0-@>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/X0NDua5G01GvzkDXwS5W8/9/9eCSosy8dHUFNBkFYy6cUga4peKNAQ)

**Explanation**

```
        0-@>]      NB. first or last index depending on sign of right arg
     A.~           NB. get first or last Anagram of left arg
(#~|)              NB. copy left arg, absolute-value-of-right-arg times
```

Comment: `(#~|)A.~0-@>]` for 13 bytes

Comment: Very nice @miles !

Comment: No problem. You also don't need to count the parentheses used to invoke the verb.

Comment: Also 13 bytes: `#~ ::(|.@#~|)`

Comment: @FrownyFrog Nice!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
0‹FR}ʒ¹Ä×?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f4FHDTreg2lOTDu083HJ4uv3//7qmXEpKSh6pOTn5XOH5RTkpikAuAA)

**Explanation**

```
0‹F         # input_1 < 0 times do:
   R        # reverse input_2
    }       # end loop
     ʒ      # filter
      ¹Ä×   # repeat current char abs(input_1) times
         ?  # print without newline
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP>=7.1, 65 bytes

```php
for([,$s,$n]=$argv;$i<strlen($s)*abs($n);)echo$s[$i++/$n-($n<0)];
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3dc97c84fcc3abd76c0d3cdb949c5a31dbc1a326)

Comment: In integer context, `$n<0` has the same value as `$n<0?:0` but it's 3 bytes shorter :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak (BrainHack)](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>154</s> 152 bytes

```
([(({})(<()>))]<>)<>{({}()<([{}]()<([{}])>)<>({}<>)<>>)<>}{}<>{}<>({}<([][()]){{}({<({}<(({}<>)<>)>())>[()]}<{}{}>)([][()])}{}{}<>>){{}{({}<>)<>}(<>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsNADEP/JZM0ZMxmDP2GjscNaYc2FDKEbMbf7toHNwiZJ8mvaz/O7/7@RaAB5oSASnZRiloSUNDM@3RWkHwUSl53qSBab2Cn5dBkkNmlgtRKXSxHyll2Gz@0VjbrjrTkEbE@Yt1ied7XcX6WPw)

Just here to give DJMcMayhem some competition. **;)**

### Explanation

Here's a modified version of DJMcMayhem's explanation

```
#Compute the sign and negative absolute value 
([(({})<(())>)]<>)<>{({}()<([{}]()<([{}])>)<>({}<>)<>>)<>}{}<>{}<>

#Keep track of the sign
({}<

    #For each char in the input string:
    ([][()])
    {
        {}

        #Push n copies to the alternate stack
        ({<({}<(({}<>)<>)>())>[()]}<{}{}>)

        #Endwhile
        ([][()])
    }{}{}<>

#Push the sign back on
>)

#If so...
{{}

    #Reverse the whole stack
    {({}<>)<>}

    #And toggle over, ending the loop
    (<>)
}

#Pop the counter off
{}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```
f n=if n<0 then List.reverse>>f -n else List.concatMap(List.repeat n)
```

Defines `f` to be a function that takes an integer and a list of characters and returns a list of characters. You can try it [here](https://elm-lang.org/try). Here is a full test program:

```
import Html exposing (text)

f : Int -> List Char -> List Char
f n=if n<0 then List.reverse>>f -n else List.concatMap(List.repeat n)

main =
  text (String.fromList (f -3 ['S','t','r','i','n','g']))
```

#### Explanation

This is my first Elm submission, so please let me know any golfing tricks I've missed.

Using currying, we define a function `f` that takes an integer `n` and returns a function from a list of chars to a list of chars. There are two cases in the function definition:

- If `n` is negative, call `f` on its absolute value (`f -n`); then compose (`>>`) the resulting function with `List.reverse`.
- Else, create a function that puts `n` copies of a value in a list (`List.repeat n`) and map that function over each char in the list, flattening the result into a list of chars (`List.concatMap`).

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 15 bytes

```
{⌽⍣(⍵<0)⊢⍺/⍨|⍵}
```

String as a left argument, number as a right argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpHPXsf9S7WeNS71cZA81HXoke9u/Qf9a6oAQrU/v@v7pGak5OvEJ5flJOiqK6QpmDMpZ6Wnw9iGRpxqQeXFGXmpYN4h9YDZUIyMosVgChRIa00TyE5IzEnJzUvPRUkbwAA)

**How?**

`⍺/⍨` - repeat the string

`|⍵` - abs(number) times

`⌽⍣` - reverse if

`(⍵<0)` - the number is below 0

Comment: Umm, it'd be nice if the TIO like worked?

Comment: @Gryphon and here goes the byte...

Comment: Yep, I'd just realized that and was typing out my comment to tell you.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 37 bytes

```
@(s,n)flip(repelem(s,abs(n)),(n<0)+1)
```

This defines and anonymous function with inputs `s`: string and `n`: number.

Example runs:

```
>> @(s,n)flip(repelem(s,abs(n)),(n<0)+1)
ans = 
    @(s,n)flip(repelem(s,abs(n)),(n<0)+1)

>> f = ans;

>> f('String', 3)
ans =
SSStttrrriiinnnggg

>> f('String', -3)
ans =
gggnnniiirrrtttSSS

>> f('String', 0)
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Comment: Choosing which dimension to flip along was way better than the mess I wrote  +1. and I always forget `repelem` exists.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Well, you could incorporate that in your answer too :-) (+1 already). I think there's no `repelem` in Octave, for now

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>89</s> <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```java
s->n->{for(int i=s.length*(n<0?n:-n),r=n<0?0:~i;i++<0;)System.out.print(s[(i+r)/n]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLbsIwELzzFVtONhA3tDcCVBVS1R6qHqjUQ5qDCQ6YOnZkb5AQSn89dR4gVMmyrZnVzOwc@JEHphD6sP2pZV4Yi3DwGCtRKpaVOkVpNBtFg6LcKJlCqrhz8M6lhvMAoEcdcvTP0cgt5J4ja7RS7@IEuN052o4CvPRy83TPbZxM3jSujHZlLuwSMljULljqYHnOjCVSI8iFY0roHe5HRM/DJz0LNJ3YRfMPZ78ykuPxPIzo@uRQ5MyUyApvi8TFRI4tvdcJjao6as0/NgeRYpz4TCgcOlj0qQDOw1ehlIEvY9X2bjiBx2pypTJjPDJ9uIE@99KBPxx8QeCXUU1K4cfCm6muAg8Gt3Kt07e@Wl10qy5ls/olaZtz1qWl17AZ40WhToT0HdOGj8OEMjQr3@uztfxEKGU8TUWBhPiWxU7Ybm7qG@mF/remNOm5ajBorqr@Aw)

- -2 bytes thanks to @Xanderhall
- -2 bytes thanks to @Nevay

Comment: Ideas that don't work (way longer): reverse the string before, use a stream,

Comment: Save 2 bytes with `s[(n<0?-l-~i:i)/n]`

Comment: @Xanderhall Thanks! I've been looking for that one for so long my eyes bleed. I knew it was possible, I just messed everything up when implementing it.

Comment: as your function is single statement, do you need curly brackets?

Comment: @user902383 Yes, [it's mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11145970/180719). If they were optional, a lot of things would be unreadable. Also, my function is not a "single statement", but a for-loop, which encompass several statements.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by incrementing `i` in the condition `s->n->{for(int l=s.length*(n<0?-n:n),i=0;i++<l;)System.out.print(s[(n<0?i-l:i-1)/n]);}`. Another byte can be saved by iterating from -l to 0 instead (`s->n->{for(int i=s.length*(n<0?n:-n),r=n<0?0:~i;i++<0;)System.out.print(s[(i+r)/n]);}`).

Comment: @Nevay This is some really nice golfing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak (Haskell)](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>202</s> 192 bytes

```
(({})<(([({})]<>)){({}()<([{}])<>({}<>)<>>)<>}{}([{}]<><{}>)([][()]){{}({<({}<(({}<>)<>)>[()])>()}<{}{}>)([][()])}{}{}<>>)([({}<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}{{}{({}<>)<>}(<>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xDsJADEP/pZM9dGKNIvENjKcbCgNUSB2qblG@PSQHCIbo4hf7fN2XdXsst2cEYE4BWr1dlLTckKiZd4qmSipa43kpLCrmSrTewE5LbFJGfN3UcVHQ0/pv9pL13ajMBKns@DW/ewwYHanMRyJZ4U@BVyJ5RMznOMV0OfZ1u08v)

This is probably the worst possible language to do it in, but it's done. Thanks to @Wheatwizard for providing the Haskell interpreter, which allows mixed input formats. This would be about 150 bytes longer without it.

Explanation:

```
#Keep track of the first input (n)
(({})<

    #Push abs(n) (thanks WheatWizard!)
    (([({})]<>)){({}()<([{}])<>({}<>)<>>)<>}{}([{}]<><{}>)

    #For each char in the input string:
    ([][()])
    {
        {}

        #Push n copies to the alternate stack
        ({<({}<(({}<>)<>)>[()])>()}<{}{}>)

        #Endwhile
        ([][()])
    }{}{}<>

#Push the original n back on
>)

#Push n >= 0
([({}<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}

#If so...
{{}

    #Reverse the whole stack
    {({}<>)<>}

    #And toggle over, ending the loop
    (<>)
}

#Pop the counter off
{}
```

Comment: You could use my 52 byte abs to save 2 bytes, you could also use the 50 byte -abs I gave you and increment instead of decrementing to save 6 bytes.

Comment: [Some friendly competition.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132181/56656)

Answer (score 3):

## C89 bytes

```
main(int c,char**v){for(;*v[1];v[1]++)for(c=atoi(v[2]+(*v[2]=='-'));c--;)putchar(*v[1]);}
```

I saw [Ben Perlin's version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132050/22873) and wondered if you couldn't be shorter still and also have  a full program; surely, `atoi()` and `putchar()` aren't that expensive in terms of bytes? Seems I was right!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>108</s> <s>106</s> <s>103</s> 101 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
e,p,j,d;f(s,i)char*s;{p=0,e=strlen(s);for(i*=d=i<0?p=e-1,e=-1:1;p^e;p+=d)for(j=i;j--;)putchar(s[p]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8/D4IwEMVn@RSVqcU2Ad08G1d3TRz8kxBooaS2TQsT4bNjdTAxJDfd@7279yrWVNU8C@poR2uQOFBFqrb0WYDR8ZwKHnqvhcGBgLQeq4zXXB3yo@OCFVFmxb4A9xTgNrwmH6TjCjrGgLih/5zC4eYeBKZZmR69SmUwScZVspI4PQmtLbpar@t1StGOAIqmgNOUwBeQ1sZ9sV0I594r00SNLU2XVgUUp0RyMChG0LFAIyKcL9hvgrv5Rfj/NM1v)

Comment: @ceilingcat Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 49 bytes

```matlab
@(s,n){t=repmat(s,abs(n),1)(:)',flip(t)}{2-(n>0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1gnT7O6xLYotSA3sQTIS0wq1sjT1DHU1LDSVNdJy8ks0CjRrK020tXIszPQrP2fpqHukZqTk6@uY6zJheAYIHN0jTX/AwA)

I will provide an explanation tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
*sm*.aQdz._
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2asm%2a.aQdz._&input=-3%0AHello+World%21&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-3%0AHello+World%21%0A3%0AHello+World%21%0A0%0AHello+World%21&debug=0&input_size=2)

*-2 bytes thanks to @jacoblaw*

### explanation

```
*sm*.aQdz._   
  m     z     # map onto the input string (lambda var: d)
   *.aQd      # repeat the char d as often as the absolute value of the input number 
 s            # sum the list of strings into a single string
*        ._Q   # Multiply with the sign of the implicit input value: reverse for negative Q
```

### old approach, 13 bytes

```
_W<Q0sm*.aQdz
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_W%3CQ0sm%2a.aQdz&input=-3%0AHello+World%21&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-3%0AHello+World%21%0A3%0AHello+World%21%0A0%0AHello+World%21&debug=0&input_size=2)

Comment: you can save two bytes with [this](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2asm%2a.aQdz._&input=-3%0AHello+World%21&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-3%0AHello+World%21%0A3%0AHello+World%21%0A0%0AHello+World%21&debug=0&input_size=2) reversal logic

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 +1 = 60 bytes

Uses `-n` flag.

```ruby
n=eval$_
a=$<.read
a.reverse!if n<0
a.chars{|i|$><<i*n.abs}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjBCkBAEADQ@34FtSch5bqc/YGjBiNb26xm2RJ@3XB69fgYTxFqMILTg4JGm5IRZgU/ETlgapeETPXHtAKH67a3bo2xGZUwhkekqFWHzvlc9Z7dnL5@262nIAV9)

Comment: `eval$_` is shorter than `$_.to_i` by 1 byte. `String#chars` can also accept a block the same way `String#each_char` can. Finally, reverse the input before processing each character so you can print it directly instead (switching your flag to `-n`). [All of this combines to become 55+1=56 bytes.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P882tSwxRyWeK9FWxUavKDUxhSsRSJWlFhWnKmamKeTZGAAFkjMSi4qrazJrVOxsbDK18mr//zfl8kjNycnX4QrPL8pJUfyXX1CSmZ9X/F83DwA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Ｆθ¿‹η0Ｆ±Ｉη←ιＦＩηι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBo1BTITNNQcMntbhYI0NHQclASVNTASzjl5qeWJKq4ZxYXKKRoQkUDSjKzCvRsPJJTSvRUcjUVEjNKU6FKIWpgSrJ1LT@/z@4BMhO59I1/q9b9l@3OAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ              For each character in the input string
  ¿‹η0          If the input number is less than zero
      Ｆ±Ｉη      Repeat the negation of the input number times
          ←ι    Print the character leftwards (i.e. reversed)
      ＦＩη       Otherwise repeat the input number times
         ι      Print the character
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
®pVaÃ¬r!+sVg
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rnBWYcOsciErc1Zn&input=IkhlbGxvCldvcmxkISIgMg==)

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U` and integer `V`.

```
®pVaÃ
```

Map (`®`) each letter of `U` (implicitly) to itself repeated (`p`) `abs(V)` (`Va`) times.

```
¬r
```

Turn the string into an array of chars (`¬`) and reduce (`r`) that with...

```
!+sVg
```

`"!+".slice(sign(V))` - this either reduces with `+` → `a + b`, or with `!+` → `b + a`.
[Thanks @Arnauld for the backwards-reduce idea!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132008/69583)

Comment: I feel like `£gY*Vg)pVa` should lead to a shorter solution but my brain has shut down for the holidays so I can't quite figure it out. You may be able to do something with it, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
q~__*@e*%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7AuPl7LIVVL9f9/peCSosy8dCUFXWMA)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>93</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s></sub> 85 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as string from cell `[A1]` and int from cell `[B1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
l=[Len(A1)]:For i=1To l:For j=1To[Abs(B1)]:?Mid([A1],IIf([B1]>0,i,l+1-i),1);:Next j,i
```

-4 bytes for abandoning `[C1]` as intermediate variable

-1 byte for adding `a` as intermediate variable

-2 bytes for replacing `a` with `l`, (`[Len(A1)]`)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

Based off Riley's approach.

```
SÂÎ›@²Ä×J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/@HDT4b5HDbscDm063HJ4utf//x6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KYpcusYA)

#### Explanation

```
SÂÎ›@²Ä×J   Arguments: s, n
S           Push s split into individual characters
 Â          Get a (without popping) and push a reversed
  Î›        n lower than 0 (true = 1, false = 0)
    @       Get value at that index in the stack
     ²Ä×J   Repeat each character abs(n) times and join
            Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
h=lambda s,n:h(s[::-1],-n)if n<0 else s[0]*n+h(s[1:],n)if s else s*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8M2JzE3KSVRoVgnzypDozjaykrXMFZHN09TITNNIc/GQCE1pzhVoTjaIFYrTxukwNAqVgciWwyV08r7X1CUmVeikaGhnpGak5OvrmOiqckFF0vPz09JqkxV1zHDKqoLFP4PAA)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! Unfortunately, this answer is invalid right now, since it doesn't support [Negative numbers](https://tio.run/##PcixCoAgEADQva@4Ta8MiqIh6EvEoVAzsDM6l77emnrju54cEg2l@CWu52ZXYEUz687U1HjJup@NIoTDA4OL7IBrgnLdB2XppQguxiRUOyJWf@4p2e1xX0@I5QU "Python 3 – Try It Online"). The challenge says: `If the integer is negative, we use its absolute value in the first step, and then reverse the string.`

Comment: Thanks for fixing it! BTW, you could take two bytes off by removing the spaces after parenthesis `)`

Comment: Edited, thanks for the contribution

Comment: `n<0 else` => `n<0else`

Answer (score 2):

## [WendyScript](http://felixguo.me/wendy/), 46 bytes

```
<<f=>(s,x){<<n=""#i:s#j:0->x?x>0n+=i:n=i+n/>n}

f("Hello World", -2) // returns ddllrrooWW  oolllleeHH
```

[Try it online!](http://felixguo.me/#wendyScript)

### Explanation (Ungolfed):

```
let f => (s, x) {
  let n = ""
  for i : s
    for j : 0->x
      if x > 0 n += i
      else n = i + n
  ret n
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Forth, 132 bytes.

My first golf, Idk what I'm doing I'm sure it could be improved a lot.

```
: Z chars + c@ emit ; : X 0 do dup n Z loop ; : Y dup 0 < if negate then dup 0 > if n count 0 do over i 1 + swap X drop loop then ;
```

or

```
: Z chars + c@ emit ;
: X 0 do dup n Z loop ;
: Y dup 0 < if negate then dup 0 > if n count 0 do over i 1 + swap X drop loop then ;
```

The negate and comparisons are just for the 0 and negative cases.
This is assuming we've already been given the string at 'n', I'm unsure if this is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 89 bytes

```
(T=Table;t=""<>T[s[[i]]~T~Abs@#2,{i,Length[s=Characters@#]}];If[#2>0,t,StringReverse@t])&
```

**input**

> ["Hello World!", 3]

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 32 bytes

```
g=sgn(c)[_l;||[:*g|?_sA,b*g,1|';
```

### Explanation

```
            Takes inputs A$ ('Hello'), and c (-3) from the cmd line
g=sgn(c)    Save the sign of c          -1
[_l;||      FOR each char in A$
[:*g|       FOR the number of repetitions wanted    (ie: -3 * -1)
            Note that : reads a number from the cmd line, and c is the first 
            available variable to save it in after a and b got used as FOR counters.
            Also note that a negative value times the sign becomes positive.
?_s         PRINT a substring
  A         of A$
 ,b*g       startng at char n, where n is the first FOR loop counter times the sign
                That means that when c is negative, so is this. A negative starting index
                on Substring instructs QBIC to take from the right.
 ,1|        taking 1 char.
';          This bit injects a literal ; in the output QBasic, to suppress newlines om PRINT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 22 bytes

```
1-v{R.[v.R]v}R[v>R]v&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fULesOkgvukwvKLasNii6zA5Iqzn8///f@H@0uoe6joJ6KojIgRP56rEA)

Eeh, not bad.

Takes input as an integer and an array of characters.

Alternatively:

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 31 bytes

```
l1->[M]1-v&,{R.[v.R]v}R[v>R]v&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/x1DXLto31lC3TE2nOkgvukwvKLasNii6zA5Iqzn8///f@L9Hak5Ovo5CeX5RTooiAA)

Takes input as an integer and a string

Answer (score 1):

## C, 109 bytes

```
char *f(int n, char *s){char *o=calloc(n,strlen(s)+1),*t=o;while(*s){for(int i=n;i--;)*t++=*s;s++;}return o;}
```

Starting with a function declaration that takes an int and a string and produces a string (it seems implied that memory is not preallocated and must be created) it seems that the straight-forward approach is shorter than any attempts at being cleaver that I had tried.

```
char *f(int n, char *s){
  char *o=calloc(n, strlen(s)+1),
    *t=o;

  while (*s) {
    for(int i=n; i--; )
      *t++=*s;
    s++;
  }

 return o;
```

}

Comment: This does not seem to work for negative n.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 44 bytes

```
(s,x)->for i in split(s,"") print(i^abs(x))end
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work. When the integer argument is negative, the string should be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

### [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language))/[Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
{,/$[y>0;;|:]y#'x}
```

Now, in the 0 case, it does output *something*, but that's the empty string so I'm sure that's all gravy.

I actually missed the negative input part of this initially, which cost me eleven bytes! Definitely not my best work

Usage:

```
k){,/$[y>0;;|:]y#'x}["Hello World";3]
"HHHeeellllllooo   WWWooorrrlllddd!!!"
k){,/$[y>0;;|:]y#'x}["Hello World!";0]
""
k){,/$[y>0;;|:]y#'x}["String";-3]
"gggnnniiirrrtttSSS"
```

Comment: Can [trim a couple bytes](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpHX6PSxkCzxkq/Ulm9ovZ/moKeuoaGkkdqTk6@Qnh@UU6KopK1saa1hlJafr6StaERiBlcUpSZl65krQuWCMnILFYAokSFtNI8heSMxJyc1Lz0VCVrA5As2KSYPJhRRpqa/wE) by using `(y<0)|:/` instead of `$[y>0;;|:]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 89 bytes

```powershell
param($s,$n)-join($s[((0..($L=$s.Length)),(-1..-$L))[$n[0]-eq45]]|%{"$_"*"$n".trim('-')})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBDoIwDADQf1lqaA1tMOrRP9iN47IYDgtgoOBGwkH99srtvXXZUy5DmiaztcvdjFBqUOLXMurhgNiIIPgHFPFJ@20gqpEvIgyeKICGJnJ63@4xfk8fB093dqBOtjzOWHFFPzKz9qj2xtc/)

Generates a list of characters in the string, either forward or reversed, string-multiplies each, and joins the resulting array. `$n[0]-eq45` is the ASCII code of `-` and `.Trim('-')` is shorter than `[Math]::Abs($n)`

Answer (score 1):

## **C#, 70 Bytes**

```
using System.Linq;(s,n)=>string.Join("",s.Select(c=>new string(c,n)));
```

The select function is used to create a new string with the original character repeated n-times, results are joined together.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunatley your answer does not work for negatives or zero. You can also shorten your code by using currying i.e. `s=>n=>`, `string.Concat()` and you don't need the trailing semi colon.

Answer (score 1):

## **C++, 152 bytes**

```
#define l(x,n)for(int x=0;x<n;++x)
typedef std::string s;s f(s t,int c){s r;l(i,t.size())l(j,abs(c))r+=t[i];if(c<0)reverse(r.begin(),r.end());return r;}
```

And here's the full code you can test with.

```
#include <iostream>

#define l(x,n)for(int x=0;x<n;++x)
typedef std::string s;s f(s t,int c){s r;l(i,t.size())l(j,abs(c))r+=t[i];if(c<0)reverse(r.begin(),r.end());return r;}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << f("Hello World!", 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f("foo", 12) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f("String", -3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f("This is a fun challenge", 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f("Hello\nWorld!", 2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start you certainly don't need all the whitespace here.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks! I didn't know the spaces don't count.

Comment: I'm not getting the same byte count.  I'm getting 202 bytes.  If I remove all the unnecessary whitespace it goes down to 140, but I don't see where the 134 number is coming from.

Comment: @ZackLee Spaces *do* count. You can just remove a lot of them by writing the whole thing on one line and writing (for example) `for(` instead of `for (`

Comment: You need to count those `typedefs` and `defines`.  And the `#include`.  And the `using nam`...you need to count everything that isn't `main`.

Comment: @Ray Thanks! I updated my code. I didn't count "#include <iostream>" as it is a default library for C++.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 108 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>n=>{var a=s.Select(c=>new string(c,n>0?n:-n));return string.Concat(n<0?a.Reverse():a);}
```

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestBed
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, Func<int, string>> f = s => n =>
            {
                var a = s.Select(c => new string(c, n > 0 ? n : -n));

                return string.Concat(n < 0 ? a.Reverse() : a);
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f("Hello World!")(3));
            Console.WriteLine(f("foo")(12));
            Console.WriteLine(f("String")(-3));
            Console.WriteLine(f("This is a fun challenge")(0));
            Console.WriteLine(f(@"Hello
World!")(2));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, 26 bytes

```
,>>,[<<[->+>.<<]>[-<+>]>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx85OJ9rGJlrXTttOz8Ym1i5a10bbLtZOJ/b/f2aP1JycfB2F8vyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 1):

### vim, 45 bytes

```
:s/\(.\)/\1<C-v>
/g
adl<esc>gJaP<esc>"add
:%norm @a
:%j!
```

`<esc>` is 0x1b, and `<C-v>` is 0x16.

`:s/\(.\)/\1<C-v><nl>/g` splits the string into one character per line.

`adl<esc>gJaP<esc>"add` then constructs a command in buffer `a` that will copy a line `n` times, where `n` is the number that was previously on this line.

`%norm @a` and `:%j!` then apply that command to each line in the file and rejoin the lines respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pYP0ZDL0ZTP8bQxlm3zI5LP50rMSXHJrU42S7dKzEAzFBKTEnhslLNyy/KVXBIBLKyFP//90jNycnXUSjPL8pJUeQy/q9bBgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Unwanted, Unnecessary, Opportunistic](https://github.com/faso/Unwanted-Unnecessary-Opportunistic), 7 bytes

```
IAM*|V^
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 24 bytes

```
#(for[c % _(range %2)]c)
```

Returning a string instead of a sequence of characters pushes this to 35 bytes:

```
#(apply str(for[c % _(range %2)]c))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C#], 103 bytes

```
var r=n<0?-n:n;var a=new int[p.Length*r].Select((_,i)=>p[i/r]);return String.Concat(n<0?a.Reverse():a);
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VVA9a8MwEN39K66mg9QobppuUZwOhdIhU1LI4Joi3HMiECcjKelg/NtTyXGHguDpne59oMbPG6@vF@WAttoHKIHwp6qhh2cBT0sB84gLAUsYZJbWzP@t/B2NsXCwznzf5QLy1toE@@A0HdPt46Q9xKOgPRM0J2UM0hHT06j9pEmcEt7O1Kz9qBWgKQi4kQ20MZR1AohDucn6sbIrab14mdOKZKKqjK2SquqKbcwIpwdXF3s02ATGvoTm5aar9KOruXQYzo7gVrN4tdSowJKbKnZ4QeeR8ZXi8jpIyLLWOpYSdCyxkBHWt@@aYuJkNuNZnwFAtPLWYHFwOuBWE7L7fIcdqrCCfhRVuh5ESo4DM/Ho27dsYgL@9viQc5kN118)

Tried something a little different from the other C# answers, without using 'new string(str, x)'.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ȧ•?0<[Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiyKfigKI/MDxb4bmYIiwiIiwiLTMsIFwiaGVsbG8gd29ybGRcIlxuMywgXCJoZWxsbyB3b3JsZFwiXG4wLCBcImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkXCIiXQ==)

There's gotta be a better way to do this.

```
 •      # Repeat each char by...
ȧ       # absolute value of input
  ?0<[  # If it's negative
      Ṙ # Reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 61 bytes

```
:&0)?v>i:0(?^\
-$0&0/\p3a'r'&
 .07~v?:<+1&:/
{:}+1/ >o< ~\.28
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiOiYwKT92Pmk6MCg/XlxcXG4tJDAmMC9cXHAzYSdyJyZcbiAuMDd+dj86PCsxJjovXG57On0rMS8gPm88IH5cXC4yOCIsImlucHV0IjoiYWJjIiwic3RhY2siOiIzIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIn0=)

### Explanation

[image]

Takes the number as the initial stack value, and the string as the STDIN.

Uses source code modification: Inserts a `r` command at `10,3` if the number is positive. If so invert the number. The `&` instruction is nicely in the perfect place both from the top and from the right side.

The `{:}` copies the character `-n` times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
AḄ$0<?r
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKx0f7mhRMbCxL1pSnJRcDBVdsEHXmMsjNScnX0chPL8oJ0URIg4A)

##### Explanation

```python
AḄ$0<?r  # Implicit input
 Ḅ       # Multiply each character of the second input by...
A        # ...the absolute value of the first input
  $      # Push the first input again
   0<    # And check if it's negative
     ?   # If it is negative:
      r  #  Reverse the string
         # Implicit output
```

Comment: This doesn't work for cases like `String, -3`, as negative numbers need to reverse the input them multiply

Comment: @lyxal thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 56 bytes

```
""<>Thread@Table[Reverse[Characters@#2,2+Sign@#],Abs@#]&
```

[Try it at the Wolfram sandbox!](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) (Doesn't work in Mathics…)

Takes the number then the string as input.

The `Reverse` function can take a second parameter saying what level of the array to reverse at (so `Reverse[{{1,2},{3,4}}]` returns `{{3,4},{1,2}}` but `Reverse[{{1,2},{3,4}},2]` gives `{{2,1},{4,3}}`, for instance). When the input number is negative, we reverse at level 1, but when it's zero or positive, we reverse at level 2 or 3. Since `Characters@#2` is a list with only one level, reversing at deeper levels has no effect.

Once that's done, we repeat the list of characters then transpose the resulting array using `Thread` so the repeated characters end up next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 120

```
proc M s\ n {if $n<0 {set s [string rev $s];set n [expr -$n]};lmap c [split $s ""] {append x [string repe $c $n]};set x}
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/QCKUB89769)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 76 bytes

```
Os^$`(?<=^-.+¶.*).

^.+
$*
s`(?<=¶.*)
	
{`^1

}s`(?<=^1.*)	(.)
	$1$1
\`^¶|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fvzhOJUHD3sY2TldP@9A2PS1NPS6uOD1tLhUtrmKwBFiQi5OrOiHOkIurFiIYZwgU5NTQA0qoGKoYcsUkxB3aVsPJ9f@/rjFXcElRZl46AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
So?I↔>0o`ȯṁRa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzjf3vNR2xQ7g/yEE@sf7mwMSvz//7@SR2pOTr6OQnh@UU6KotJ/XSMA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
       o`ȯṁ    -- with the input string..
           Ra  -- ..multiply each character by the absolute value |N|
So?            -- depending on N either apply..
   I           -- ..the identity..
     >0        -- ..if N>0 or else..
    ↔          -- ..reverse it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÆVÃÕzUÌÉ©2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=xlbD1XpVzMmpMg&input=LTIKIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISI)

```
ÆVÃÕzUÌÉ©2     :Implicit input of integer U & string V
Æ              :Map the range [0,U)
 V             :  Return V
  Ã            :End map
   Õ           :Transpose
    z          :Rotate clockwise this many times
     UÌ        :  Sign of difference between U & -1
       É       :  Subtract 1
        ©2     :  Logical AND with 2
               :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 80 bytes

```c
i;L;f(s,n)char*s;{L=strlen(s);for(i=0;i*i<L*n*L*n;)putchar(s[i++/n+~-L*(n<0)]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xDoIwEIZneIrK1BaIqOPB7sCmiYM6EKRwSb2aFiaCr46VwcSQ3C33f3f31Wlb1/OMUILiLiFRd5WVDsaycL3VDXEnQBnLscgAJealJOkbxGvovyx3V4zjLcXvtJSc8kzcBUwzUs@eFRIX4RiEgeLRsdHasIux@rGJEnYQwPwJx6NIwAIoY/x8t18Fp94itT5L10vnDh3zVTE1EPNC2ju3jYezFbsY3Oin8P9pmj8)

-1 byte from ceilingcat

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org),  50 bytes

```
{($^a.comb »x»$^b.abs).join.&{$b <0??.flip!!$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/gh1v4uken6)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
n=>g=(h,i=n,[c,...x]=h)=>c?i?i>0?c+g(h,i-1):g(h,i+1)+c:g(x):h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY69CsIwGEX3PkXcEtqGtm6VpKu7goMIDWn@JOSTtkrfPqaCDhbucOGcC/cuXmKSo3vMZYBBRc1iYNwwbAvHQnGVBaV0uTFLGJed6xyvOpmbFZc1aT8lr0kuU11Ia@MhkxAm8Ip6MFjjPcH9UXkP6AKjH3Y9IX9G3SRFA2xJuY5P8@iC2cIqsbN1E0oRSD8DklZ4r4JRW7n5vsh@L@Ib)

No longer longer than Q256411, but even same length it's only