# How many times will you have to golf a quine?

Tags: code-golf, quine

For this challenge, you must create a programme which takes an integer `x` and outputs its source `x` many times.

**Rules**

- This is codegolf, the aim is to golf your programme to have the least amount of bytes
- If you submit a function, the function must take `x` as  a parameter and either return or print the entirety of your code `x` many times to STDOUT. The function body must also not be empty
- If you submit a lambda, it is not required for you to assign it to a variable
- [Standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) restrictions apply.
- Empty programmes are forbidden
- Your programme only has to work when `x` is a whole integer larger than or equal to 0
- Your programme may also not directly read any part of its source code

Comment: Nice first Question

Comment: Can `x` be `0`, or can we restrict it to positive integers?

Comment: Is reading the source of our function permitted?

Comment: @mbomb007, I've made an edit to clarify the rules, `x` maybe any whole integer larger than or equal to 0

Comment: @Shaggy, I thought that was a standard loophole, it seems as if it was not. I've made an edit to the question to clearly state that a programme may not read any part of the part of its source code

Comment: I think the consensus for quines is that reading of source code is not permitted by default. I always hold out hope, though, because, without reading the source, creating quines make my brain itchy!

Comment: I disagree with the reading of sourcecode, as it "Defeats the purpose" of a quine. It's easy to `cat $0`, it's difficult to programmatically create yourself.

Comment: @Spammy23: It's not a standard loophole, but it *is* a default rule for [tag:quine] challenges, so it was disallowed all along. That said, given that this question is solvable via universal quine constructors, I'm not sure how much it adds to existing quine challenges.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62711/quine-multiple-times?noredirect=1&lq=1), but not a duplicate because the problem is significantly changed by not having to handle negative inputs.

Comment: "Your programme may also not directly read any part of its source code". So I guess using a Rexx function called Sourceline(x) which returns line x in the source is a no-no. :)

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Spammy23 Does that mean no string literals? :P

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

Note the trailing comma and newline.

```python
s='s=%r;print s%%s*input(),\n';print s%s*input(),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19sq15sq1pkXVCUmVeiUKyqWqyVmVdQWqKhqROTpw4XRohy/f9vBAA)

Comment: @mbomb007 Assume there is a newline at the end of the code. Problem solved.

Comment: The OP said that x can be zero, in which case nothing should be printed, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: @NickA No, it prints a newline, which is wrong.

Comment: 0 doesn't seem to print a newline to me, as tested by using `sys.stdout.write("2")` after it.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
"iQ ²pU"iQ ²pU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@6@UGahwaFNBKIz@/98IAA)

## Explanation

```
"iQ ²pU"iQ ²pU
"iQ ²pU"       # Take this string
        iQ     # Prepend a quote
           ²   # Double the string (= source code)
            pU # Duplicate input times
```

Answer (score 5):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 8 bytes

```
{`{.*¶}{
```

The RProgN2 Loop quine works particularly well for this!

```
{     } # A function literal
       {# Without a matching }, this loops back to the second instruction, which essentially runs the function. This is a bug, but it works to make the "Looping Quine".
 `{.    # Append the literal {, stringifying the function.
    *   # Multiply the stringified function by the input.
     ¶  # Terminate the program.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/786oVpP69C22ur///@bAgA)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>40</s> 33 bytes

*Thanks to lanlock4 for saving 7 bytes!*

```
StringRepeat[ToString[#0], #1] &
```

Pure function taking a nonnegative integer argument. `ToString[#0]` is the standard Mathematica way to access the current pure function's definition; `StringRepeat[..., #1]` concatenates (input) copies of that string together. For example,

```
StringRepeat[ToString[#0], #1] & [2]
```

yields:

```
StringRepeat[ToString[#0], #1] & StringRepeat[ToString[#0], #1] &
```

Comment: Could you post a usage example? Running, *e.g.*, `StringJoin @@ Table[ToString[#0], #1] & [2]` gives me an error.

Comment: Really? That exact call works for me. I'm using Mathematica 11....

Comment: Hmm, I'm still using 10 (v10.0.1.0)—that could be it. For reference, here's the error that I get: `Table::itform: Argument 2 at position 2 does not have the correct form for an iterator.`

Comment: Aha—I discover that `Table[x,5]` will return `{x,x,x,x,x}` in Mathematica 10.2 and beyond, but in Mathematica 10.1 it gives such an error (it expects `Table[x,{5}]`).

Comment: I think you can replace `StringJoin @@ Table` with `StringRepeat`.

Comment: I can once I know about the command! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 70 bytes

This solution works if `x=0`. There is a single trailing newline.

```python
s='s=%r;exec"print%%r;"%%(s%%s)*input()';exec"print%r;"%(s%s)*input()
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19sq15sq1pknVqRmqxUUJSZV6IK5CmpqmoUq6oWa2pl5hWUlmhoqiMrAMkDpRGyXP//mwIA)

---

### Python 2, 60 bytes (invalid)

This assumes that `x>=1`, but the OP clarified that `x` can be zero. There is a single trailing newline.

```python
s='s=%r;print(s%%s*input())[:-1]\n';print(s%s*input())[:-1]
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19sq15sq1pkXVCUmVeiUayqWqyVmVdQWqKhqRltpWsYG5OnDpdDk@L6/98UAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 11 bytes

```
ÀñAÀÑ~"qpx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@44fBGRyAxsU5aqbCg4v///8YA)

This is an extremely trivial modification of the [standard extensible V quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100426/31716). We simply use `À` to run it *arg1* times.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 31 bytes

```
[[1-rd91Pn93P[dx]Pdx]s.rd0<.]dx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#M/4fHW2oW5RiaRiQZ2kcEJ1SERsAxMV6RSkGNnqxKRX//wMA)

Explanation:

```
[[1-rd91Pn93P[dx]Pdx]s.rd0<.]dx
[     91Pn93P[dx]P          ]dx  # Same old regular quine
 [1-rd            dx]s.rd0<.     # Loop until the counter is zero
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
*E îQi"*E îQi"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/X8tV4fC6wEwlGP3/vxEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 12 bytes

```
(a(:^)*~^):^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#07CystLS0tL8r5GoYRWnqVUXp2kV9z/4PwA)

Function submission, because Underload has no other way to take input. (The TIO link shows the number 4 given as input, and adds code to print the resulting output).

This is just a universal quine constructor `(a(:^)*):^`, plus `~^` ("make a number of copies equal to the argument").

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

```
"34çìDJ¹.D»"34çìDJ¹.D»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@69kbHJ4@eE1Ll6Hduq5HNqNxuX6/98AAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
_="input('_=%r;exec _'%_*input())";exec _
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P95WKTOvoLREQz3eVrXIOrUiNVkhXl01XgsiqqmpBBX7/98YAA)

Does a kinda hacky output using `input` instead of `print`, since `print` has a weird bug involving printing a newline when it [isn't supposed to...](https://tio.run/##HcyxCoAgFEbh3acQQ65GONQYPcsdSsghFf2jenqLljN8w8kP9hTH1nhRuYQI4kWX2d9@NWxJcx9iPmHsoH6U3MKRU4GsT51F99VVbOmEu0qAN0RWdP9JEnwFtekF). Exits with an EOF error.

#### Explanation:

```python
_="input('_=%r;exec _'%_*input())"; # Set _ to a string
exec _                              # Execute that string
input(                        )     # "print"
      '_=%r;exec _'%_               # The source code with _ formatted in
                     *input()       # Actual input many times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>20</s> 12 bytes

8 bytes saved thanks to Martin Ender

```
{"_~"+ri*}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@tFF@npF2UqVUbX/f/vykA)

#### Exaplanation

```
{       e# Begin a block literal:
 "_~"+  e#  Add whatever's on the stack to the beginning of the array ['_', '~'].
 ri*    e#  Repeat the resulting array a number of times equal to the input.
}       e# Close the block. Push it on the stack.
_~      e# Copy it and run it.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
“;⁾vṾẋɠ”vṾ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY71o8Z9ZQ937nu4q/vkgkcNc0Hs//@NAQ)

#### How it works

```
“;⁾vṾẋɠ”vṾ  Main link. No arguments.

“;⁾vṾẋɠ”    Set the argument and the return value to the string ';⁾vṾẋɠ'.
         Ṿ  Uneval; yield '“;⁾vṾẋɠ”'.
        v   Eval ';⁾vṾẋɠ' with argument '“;⁾vṾẋɠ”'.
  ⁾vṾ           Yield 'vṾ'.
 ;              Concatenate '“;⁾vṾẋɠ”' and 'vṾ', yielding the source code.
      ɠ         Read an integer from STDIN.
     ẋ          Repeat the source code that many times.
```

Comment: This looks delicious, but my mama always told me not to put strange looking things into my mouth.

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), 49 bytes

```
$(foreach ,$(shell seq $1),$(strip $(value $0)))
```

Make will join the copies by a single space, so I have to include the additional space character at the end and remove it with a `strip` in between in order to follow the requirement faithfully.

Comment: That looks like it reads the source code, which is both by default and explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen No, it doesn't read the source, it reads a variable value. It's exactly the same principle as in other answers, take for example JS or Python.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oh, I see. `$0` in Make functions is not the same thing as in shells. It's the name of the variable the function is called as. See https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function

Comment: *Sigh* such a gray area. BTW, the Python ones do *not* do this.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I'd say that this answer is much closer to Python's than it is to JS's. All `call` is doing is substituting `$0` and `$1` with actual parameters — it's simple string interpolation, just like Python's `%`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
j*]jN*2]"j*]jN*2]
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2a%5DjN%2a2%5D%22j%2a%5DjN%2a2%5D&input=3&debug=0)

Trivial extension to the pretty-well-known `jN*2]"jN*2]` quine, but can probably be golfed down

Answer (score 1):

### [Betaload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Betaload), 203 bytes

Newlines added for clarity:

```
(a(:^)*(!()):#(}:(:)~^a((::*:**:*)*)~*(~*)*~(*)~^a*(*)*{)>(0)(!()){:^}(1)(){:^}(2)(:*){:^}(
3)(::**){:^}(4)(:*:*){:^}(5)(::*:**){:^}(6)(:*::**){:^}(7)(::*::***){:^}(8)(:*:*:*){:^}(9)(
::**::**){:^}R^^S):^
```

I gave myself the restriction that it must read from STDIN rather than from the top of the stack like an Underload answer typically would. I also used proper, decimal input, which makes up most of the code.

#### Explanation:

I wrap the program up in a quine-wrapper: `(a(:^)*` and `):^`. This means all code inside the quine wrapper will have the program's source code at the bottom of the stack.

In order to convert digits into a normal Church numeral, I use the technique of replacing each digit with the code to multiply by 10 and add that digit:

```
0 -> (::*:**:*)*
1 -> (::*:**:*)*(:)~*(*)*
2 -> (::*:**:*)*(::)~*(**)*
3 -> (::*:**:*)*(:::)~*(***)*
```

There's a lot of repetition here, so let's package it up into a subprogram that will take a Church numeral from the top of the stack and use it to construct the "digit string:"

```
:(:)~^a((::*:**:*)*)~*(~*)*~(*)~^a*(*)*
```

I put this into a new environment so that it can be accessed quickly:

```
#(}:(:)~^a((::*:**:*)*)~*(~*)*~(*)~^a*(*)*{)>
```

Now I can create the replacement code for `R`. `R` uses the top elements of the stack to form a lookup table to replace a string from STDIN with Betaload code. It works like this:

```
()
(0)(code for 0)
(1)(code for 1)
(2)(code for 2)
...
R
```

However, we can use the subprogram we just made to generate the code segments:

```
(0)(!()){:^}
(1)(){:^}
(2)(:*){:^}
(3)(::**){:^}
...
```

When `R` is run, it will transform the input into a series of subprograms that build up a Church numeral. When this subprogram is executed, it creates that Church numeral on the next element on the stack (0, which was placed down earlier). This means that, after `R^`, the top value on the stack will be the Church numeral. We then `^` one more time to apply the Church numeral to the final element in the stack (the program's source code) to get the answer.

Fun fact: I've had the MD for this submission for several months. I'd kept it after misunderstanding a question (that I can't seem to find anymore). I had to dig it up from my Recycle Bin to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 48 bytes

```
print"$_\47"x(2*pop)for'print"$_\47"x(2*pop)for'
```

`\47` is the octal escape for a single quote (`'`). It is interpreted inside double quotes (`"`), but not inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, <s>27</s> 37 bytes

```
_=>alert(`${f.name}=${f}`.repeat(_))
```

**Edit**

+10 bytes if `f=` should be also displayed

---

```js
f=

_=>alert(`${f.name}=${f}`.repeat(_))

f(2);
```

Comment: @Downvoter why ?

Comment: @Kaiido I don't know.. Should I keep the `f=` ?

Comment: Your code is reading itself by implicitly calling `toString` on the function.

Comment: @acbabis Calling `f.toString()` or `f` is the same but it won't display the function name

Comment: I believe what @acbabis meant is that it violates the last point of the challenge "Your programme may also not directly read any part of its source code" - using `f` that way is referring to its own source.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 194 bytes

```
<?php $a="PD9waHAgJGE9IiMiOyRpPSRhcmd2WzFdO3doaWxlKCRpLS0pZWNobyBzdHJfcmVwbGFjZShjaHIoMzUpLCRhLGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJGEpKTs=";$i=$argv[1];while($i--)echo str_replace(chr(35),$a,base64_decode($a));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#DczbCoIwGADgV4nYhUJB2QHEJDp5yg5oJhgRv9tqK2VDI8uXN@8/vmY2l0x2EJjd41qvwFk8PHuju3zHD79AHsOA4ZxocW2Rw4gIiL/ZdhVIPxzIJN6L9LesiePdcX6uUtt6JiF7guOKXR1JfxUw3/YY1iJtb@mv1n8SOxLtL7en0uwaiJsIisfnMrwaFeMZVRDv91WKmeiU7@JWUJkBpgpmhTKaqD0EvRRKOh3fCMWCtBxU1WiaZvgH)

Not golfy at all, as b64 quines tend to be.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>257</s> 254 bytes

This pains me.

```
package main;import(."fmt";."strings";."strconv";."os");func main(){s:="package main;import(.\"fmt\";.\"strings\";.\"strconv\";.\"os\");func main(){s:=%q;n,_:=Atoi(Args[1]);Print(Repeat(Sprintf(s,s),n))}";n,_:=Atoi(Args[1]);Print(Repeat(Sprintf(s,s),n))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#lYzLCgIhGEZfJYRAQQai3cgs5g2ilk2EiIqEl/H/axM9u2m3TW3afeeDc0qS6iStXnjpgnA@xYy0I8YjER0BzC5YeE0Vw6XNCIQJcw7qIVF2hX4gPztTC03Vmd6pD7TYE2I9v3rLWQR@7IcRo6NjtrBfHZjY1AbSrU5aIt2lRoYCB8YDYzfyv1JKWd8B)

Answer (score 1):

## Microscript II, 22 bytes:

```
"v{lqp}sN*h"v{lqp}sN*h
```

## Microscript II, 20 bytes (but technically invalid as it accesses the source code of a code block):

```
{s""+`"~sN*"s`+}~sN*
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 69 Bytes

```
s='s=%r\nx=int(input())\nprint(s%%s*x)\n'
x=int(input())
print(s%s*x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>144</s> 116 bytes

```
i;main(a){for(i=getchar()-48;i--;)printf(a="i;main(a){for(i=getchar()-48;i--;)printf(a=%c%s%c,34,a,34);}",34,a,34);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0"D34çý×?"D34çý×?
```

Modification of the default [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) [`0"D34çý"D34çý`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97899/52210) by adding `×?`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7D0@3R2L@/28MAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
0                   # Push 0 to the stack
                    #  STACK: [0]
 "D34çý×?"          # Push the string 'D34çý×?' to the stack
                    #  STACK: [0, 'D34çý×?']
          D         # Duplicate this string
                    #  STACK: [0, 'D34çý×?', 'D34çý×?']
           34ç      # Push '"' to the stack
                    #  STACK: [0, 'D34çý×?', 'D34çý×?', '"']
              ý     # Join the stack by this '"' delimiter
                    #  STACK: ['0"D34çý×?"D34çý×?']
               ×    # Repeat the string the (implicit) input amount of times
                    #  input = 2 → STACK: ['0"D34çý×?"D34çý×?0"D34çý×?"D34çý×?']
                ?   # Output to STDOUT without trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 115 bytes

```cs
n=>{var s="n=>{{var s={0}{1}{0};for(int i=0;i++<n;)Write(s,(char)34,s);}}";for(int i=0;i++<n;)Write(s,(char)34,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O@YXJKZn2eTmVdil2b7P8/WrrossUih2FYJxISyqw1qqw1rgaR1Wn6RBlCpQqatgXWmtrZNnrVmeFFmSapGsY5GckZikaaxiU6xpnVtrRLRSv9bc6VpGGpa/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
"34çs«DJ¹FD,"34çs«DJ¹FD,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@69kbHJ4efGh1S5eh3a6ueigcbn@/zcBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
*jN*2]"*jN*2]
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2ajN%2a2%5D%22%2ajN%2a2%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3&debug=0)

The standard Pyth quine plus two `*` for the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
`I*`I*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJgSSpgSSoiLCIiLCI0Il0=)

Quine cheese (סּ͡͡ ◞סּ͡͡ )

### Explained

```
`I*`I*­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
`I*`    # ‎⁡The string "I*"
    I   # ‎⁢with itself quoted, prepended
     *  # ‎⁣Repeated input times
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).